# How to redirect with post data with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect

for example I'am in page `http://example/test/1` then when I click button it will redirect to `http://example/text/123` with data

in my code its more like post first then redirect

here's my code

```
$( document ).on("click", "#bill", function(){
        $('input[name="bill_number"]');
          var bill = $(this);
          var data = {
            bill_number: bill.parentsUntil("tr").parent().find("[name='bill_number']").val(),
          };

          $.ajax({
            url: '{{ route("monthly_bill.slip", $bill_period_id) }}',
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
              window.location.href = '{{ route("monthly_bill.slip", $bill_period_id) }}';
              // fn.notif("Slip printed", "success")
            }
          });
    });
```

the problem is when I used above `ajax` it will only return one parameter when redirect so I'am thingking to make it redirect with post data not post then redirect

how do I solve this problem ?

Comment: If you're directing the user to the target page anyway, why use AJAX *at all*?  Just post a form to that page.

Comment: I used datatables

Comment: "Datatables" doesn't appear to have anything to do with this.  You have a single `#bill` clickable element which finds a single nearby `bill_number` form element and submits that value via AJAX.  Just make that structure into a form and let the browser submit the value to the next page, taking the user along with it.  There's no sense in making two identical requests to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you can have some redirect logic in back-end, I used it too, try receiving a clear, fully formed URL from the back-end. I use something like this in success:

```
success: function(response) {
        try{
            obj = JSON.parse(response);
            if(obj.location != ''){
                    window.location.href = obj.location;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(e){
            alert("Malformed server answer.");
        }
}
```